# C program for a reverse triangle pattern

Tags: c, for-loop, printf, nested-loops

I want to draw a pattern like this:

```
567898765
 4567654
  34543
   232
    1
```

But I can't seem to figure it out, because this is the output I'm currently getting:

```
567898765
 45678987654
  3456789876543
   234567898765432
    12345678987654321
```

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int a, b, c, s;
  for (a = 5; a >= 1; a--) {
    for (s = a; s <= 4; s++) {
      printf(" ");
    }
    for (b = a; b <= 9; b++) {
      printf("%d", b);
    }
    for (c = 8; c >= a; c--) {
      printf("%d", c);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have a look [here](https://talentbattle.in/important-coding-questions-for-placement/write-a-program-to-print-palindromic-pyramid-pattern-printing)

Comment: You should break this problem down to parts: first figure out a way to print `567898765` given `5`, then loop that so you get a left-aligned triangle; then figure out how many spaces to print at the start of each line to center-align it.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text, post text as properly formatted text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got it mostly right, only the constant values `9` and `8` in the `b` and `c` loops are inappropriate, since the triangle's central axis isn't always `9`; the values are `2*a-1` and `2*a-2`, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Always try to write a more generic code without using magic numbers like `5`  and `9`. It can occur such a way that an invalid code will give the expected result for some magic numbers though for other numbers it will not work.

Also declare variables in minimum scopes where they are used.

The main reason of the incorrect output of your program is using the magic numbers `9` and `8` in these for loops.

```
for (b = a; b <= 9; b++) {
  printf("%d", b);
}
for (c = 8; c >= a; c--) {
  printf("%d", c);
}
```

I can suggest the following solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    const unsigned int MAX_HEIGHT = 50;

    while (1)
    {
        unsigned int n;

        printf( "Enter the height of a triangle not greater than %u (0 - exit): " , MAX_HEIGHT );

        if (scanf( "%u", &n ) != 1 || n == 0) break;

        int width = 1 + snprintf( NULL, 0, "%d", 2 * n - 1 );

        putchar( '\n' );

        for (unsigned int i = n; i != 0; --i)
        {
            printf( "%*u", ( n - i + 1 ) * width, i );

            size_t j = 1;

            for (; j < i; j++)
            {
                printf( "%*u", width, i + j );
            }

            --j;
            while (j-- != 0)
            {
                printf( "%*u", width, i + j );
            }

            putchar( '\n' );
        }

        putchar( '\n' );
    }
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter the height of a triangle not greater than 50 (0 - exit): 10

 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10
     9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10  9
        8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 14 13 12 11 10  9  8
           7  8  9 10 11 12 13 12 11 10  9  8  7
              6  7  8  9 10 11 10  9  8  7  6
                 5  6  7  8  9  8  7  6  5
                    4  5  6  7  6  5  4
                       3  4  5  4  3
                          2  3  2
                             1

Enter the height of a triangle not greater than 50 (0 - exit): 5

 5 6 7 8 9 8 7 6 5
   4 5 6 7 6 5 4
     3 4 5 4 3
       2 3 2
         1

Enter the height of a triangle not greater than 50 (0 - exit): 1

 1

Enter the height of a triangle not greater than 50 (0 - exit): 0
```